# Way to get ParseObjects to custom Search suggestions in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-contentprovider, android-search, search-suggestion

I want to ask, if is there some way to get ParseObjects to Search suggestions-box in Android. I've succesully created recent-query suggestions and it worked well. But right now do I need to put there one string collection from Parse.com while the user is typing -show results, which contain the query which is being typed. I am kind of desperated because I've been searching for it for a week and no result.

Do you have any idea, how to accomplish that?

My in normal ParseQuery in SearchActivity:

```
ParseQuery<Animal> squery = ParseQuery.getQuery(Animal.class);

        squery.whereMatches("animal", query, "i");
        squery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Animal>() {

    @Override
     public void done(List<Animal> animals, ParseException error) {


      if(animals != null){
        nAdapter.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < animals.size(); i++) {
            mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.search_loading_animals);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            nAdapter.add(animals.get(i));

              }  
         }
    }
 });
```

SuggestionAdapter to which do i need to implement the ParseQuery:

```
public class SuggestionProvider extends ContentProvider {
    private static final String TAG = "SuggestionProvider";

    private static final int SEARCH_SUGGESTIONS = 1;

    private static final UriMatcher sURLMatcher = new UriMatcher(
            UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

    static {
        sURLMatcher.addURI("*", SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY,
                SEARCH_SUGGESTIONS);
        sURLMatcher.addURI("*", SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY + "/*",
                SEARCH_SUGGESTIONS);
    }

    private static final String[] COLUMNS = new String[] {
            "_id",
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_ACTION,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_QUERY
    };

    public SuggestionProvider() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri url, String[] projectionIn, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sort) {
        int match = sURLMatcher.match(url);
        switch (match) {
            case SEARCH_SUGGESTIONS:
                String query = url.getLastPathSegment();
                MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(COLUMNS);
                String[] suffixes = { "", "a", " foo", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" };


                for (String suffix : suffixes) {
                   Toast.makeText(getContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    addRow(cursor, query + suffix);
                }
                return cursor;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL: " + url);
        }
    }

    private void addRow(MatrixCursor cursor, String string) {
        long id = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.newRow().add(id).add(string).add(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH).add(string);
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri url) {
        int match = sURLMatcher.match(url);
        switch (match) {
            case SEARCH_SUGGESTIONS:
                return SearchManager.SUGGEST_MIME_TYPE;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL: " + url);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri url, ContentValues values, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("update not supported");
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri url, ContentValues initialValues) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("insert not supported");
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri url, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("delete not supported");
    }
}
```

Comment: and what do you have problems with?

Comment: looks easy, use synchronous inside query and then translate result to MatrixCursor ...

Comment: @Selvin Till now I didnt have any bigger problem with android programming. But this appears like Narnia for me. So what do I have to set in Cursor?

Comment: @pskink i can not set the data to suggestions-box

Comment: `squery.find()` return `List<T>` iterate it instead iterating `suffixes` get some text property from `T` and pass to `addRow`

Comment: I get, how you mean it. But how can i get the collection of strings from parse, to replace it with suffixes?

Comment: I finally got it. @Selvin you saved me!!! thanks a million